# Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' spring-mvc,data

Tags: java, spring, entitymanager

again:). I've asked so many questions before, in my project. Now i almost finish it. And also, have one problem. It's

```
18:56:40.696 [RMI TCP Connection(5)-127.0.0.1] WARN  o.s.w.c.s.XmlWebApplicationContext#544 Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt
org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in ServletContext resource [/WEB-INF/appconfig-data.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1578) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:545) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:482) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:305) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:230) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:301) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:196) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.getBean(AbstractApplicationContext.java:1045) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:824) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:537) ~[spring-context-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.configureAndRefreshWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:446) [spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(ContextLoader.java:328) [spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:107) [spring-web-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4727) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5189) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:752) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:728) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:734) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.manageApp(HostConfig.java:1702) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.11]
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_91]
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_91]
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:482) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
at org.apache.catalina.mbeans.MBeanFactory.createStandardContext(MBeanFactory.java:431) [catalina.jar:8.5.11]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:300) [tomcat-coyote.jar:8.5.11]
at com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:819) [na:1.8.0_91]
at com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:801) [na:1.8.0_91]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1468) [na:1.8.0_91]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.access$300(RMIConnectionImpl.java:76) [na:1.8.0_91]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl$PrivilegedOperation.run(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1309) [na:1.8.0_91]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.doPrivilegedOperation(RMIConnectionImpl.java:1401) [na:1.8.0_91]
at javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectionImpl.invoke(RMIConnectionImpl.java:829) [na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.rmi.server.UnicastServerRef.dispatch(UnicastServerRef.java:324) [na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:200) [na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport$1.run(Transport.java:197) [na:1.8.0_91]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.rmi.transport.Transport.serviceCall(Transport.java:196) [na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport.handleMessages(TCPTransport.java:568) [na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run0(TCPTransport.java:826) [na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.lambda$run$0(TCPTransport.java:683) [na:1.8.0_91]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.8.0_91]
at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$ConnectionHandler.run(TCPTransport.java:682) [na:1.8.0_91]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) ~[na:1.8.0_91]
Caused by: javax.persistence.PersistenceException: [PersistenceUnit: default] Unable to build Hibernate SessionFactory
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.persistenceException(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:1249) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.access$600(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:120) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:860) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:850) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.boot.registry.classloading.internal.ClassLoaderServiceImpl.withTccl(ClassLoaderServiceImpl.java:425) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:849) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:152) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.createNativeEntityManagerFactory(LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:338) ~[spring-orm-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.orm.jpa.AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.afterPropertiesSet(AbstractEntityManagerFactoryBean.java:318) ~[spring-orm-4.0.9.RELEASE.jar:4.0.9.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.invokeInitMethods(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1637) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1574) ~[spring-beans-4.2.0.RELEASE.jar:4.2.0.RELEASE]
... 57 common frames omitted
Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.chat.my.model.UserEntity.roles[com.chat.my.model.Role]
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1135) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:794) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:729) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:70) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.originalSecondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1697) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.secondPassCompile(Configuration.java:1426) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.cfg.Configuration.buildSessionFactory(Configuration.java:1846) ~[hibernate-core-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl$4.perform(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:857) ~[hibernate-entitymanager-4.3.11.Final.jar:4.3.11.Final]
... 65 common frames omitted
```

I think it's becouse of my Entity class have other name then table in database, but im not sure. Also i ve child-class from Entity class(it's possible) As i understand SessionFactory can't be created.. But why not?)
Connection with db is succesfully. I've tested.

Here is my Entity classes:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
public class UserEntity {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "username")
protected String username;

@Column(name = "password")
protected String password;

@Transient
private String confirmPassword;

@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<Role> roles;

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getUsername() {
    return username;
}

public void setUsername(String username) {
    this.username = username;
}

public String getPassword() {
    return password;
}

public void setPassword(String password) {
    this.password = password;
}

public String getConfirmPassword() {
    return confirmPassword;
}

public void setConfirmPassword(String confirmPassword) {
    this.confirmPassword = confirmPassword;
}

public Set<Role> getRoles() {
    return roles;
}

public void setRoles(Set<Role> roles) {
    this.roles = roles;
}
```

}

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "roles")
public class RoleEntity{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
private Long id;

@Column(name = "name")
private String name;

@ManyToMany(mappedBy = "roles")
private Set<User> users;

public RoleEntity() {
}

public Long getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Long id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public Set<User> getUsers() {
    return users;
}

public void setUsers(Set<User> users) {
    this.users = users;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Role{" +
            "id=" + id +
            ", name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", users=" + users +
            '}';
}
```

}

Child-class:

```
public class User extends UserEntity implements Comparable {

private boolean isOnline;
private String sex;
private int age;
private String comment;
private String email;
private String friendsLogins;
private Session session;

public User(String login, String password) {
     this.sex = null;
    this.comment = null;
    this.email = null;
    this.friendsLogins = "";

}

public User(User user) {
    this.sex = user.getSex();
    this.comment = user.getComment();
    this.email = user.getComment();
    this.friendsLogins = "";

}

public User(String login, String password, boolean isOnline, String sex, int age, String comment, String email) {
    this.sex = sex;
    this.age = age;
    this.comment = comment;
    this.email = email;
    this.friendsLogins = "";
}

public Session getSession() {
    return session;
}

public void setSession(Session session) {
    this.session = session;
}


public boolean isOnline() {
    return isOnline;
}

public void setOnline(boolean online) {
    isOnline = online;
}

public String getSex() {
    return sex;
}

public void setSex(String sex) {
    this.sex = sex;
}

public int getAge() {
    return age;
}

public void setAge(int age) {
    this.age = age;
}

public String getComment() {
    return comment;
}

public void setComment(String comment) {
    this.comment = comment;
}

public String getEmail() {
    return email;
}

public void setEmail(String email) {
    this.email = email;
}

public String getFriendsLogins() {
    return friendsLogins;
}

public void setFriendsLogins(String friendsLogins) {
    this.friendsLogins = friendsLogins;
}

public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    User user = (User) obj;
    if (user.getPassword().equals(this.password) && user.getUsername().equals(this.username)) {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}


@Override
public int compareTo(Object o) {
    User user = (User) o;
    if (user.getPassword().equals(this.password) && user.getUsername().equals(this.username)) {
        return 0;
    } else if (user.getAge() > this.getAge()) {
        return -1;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

}

And xml-file:

```
  <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="${jdbc.driverClassName}"/>
    <property name="url" value="${jdbc.url}"/>
    <property name="username" value="${jdbc.username}"/>
    <property name="password" value="${jdbc.password}"/>
</bean>

<bean id="entityManagerFactory" class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource"/>
    <property name="packagesToScan" value="com.chat.my.model"/>
    <property name="jpaVendorAdapter">
        <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.vendor.HibernateJpaVendorAdapter"/>
    </property>
    <property name="jpaProperties">
        <props>
            <prop key="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect</prop>
            <prop key="hibernate.show_sql">true</prop>
        </props>
    </property>
</bean>

<bean id="transactionManager"
      class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager">
    <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
</bean>

<tx:annotation-driven/>
<jpa:repositories base-package="com.chat.my.dao"/>
```

So, i cant understand why. Before i add some classes into, i had no issues like above. 
Please help to solve)

Joke for kind ppl:)

Germans go to supermarket by BMW and go abroad by Mercedes;
French go to supermarket by Renault and go abroad by Peugeot;
Russians go to supermarket by trolleybus and go abroad by tanks.

Comment: Can you paste complete stacktrace?

Comment: I think would be better if give git.. https://github.com/lars1son/MyChat1.3

Comment: But to find the exact rootcause, we need to see exception stacktrace

Comment: ok, sorry, one sec

Comment: I hope, that's it?

Comment: Your actual RootCause is coming as `Caused by: org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.chat.my.model.UserEntity.roles[com.chat.my.model.Role]` Mapping problem betwen UserEntity and Role class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `UserEntity` class, you are mapping `Role`.  But in your code posted you have a class called `RoleEntity`, is that the one you're actually trying to map?

```
@ManyToMany
@JoinTable(name = "user_roles", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "role_id"))
private Set<Role> roles;
```

Should it instead be this?

```
private Set<RoleEntity> roles;
```

Comment: seems like truth, so, in userentity, anntotation must be also changed..!?

Comment: I would think in `RoleEntity.java` you would also need to change `private Set<User> users;` to `private Set<UserEntity> users;`  But I'm not entirely certain how things are mapping in your project.